# Change image in GTK window on function call

Tags: c, image, gtk, media-player, gtk3

I am writing a C program to display raw images using GTK. Now that I can display an image, I'd like to increase the functionality to display multiple images back-to-back in the same window (like a media player). This program is to be used in conjunction with an image decoder that updates the image buffers as more images are decoded, and GTK will follow update the window to let us know we have decoded the images correctly.

Since gtk_main() is the last function to be called, I have opened a separate thread to setup the window and keep it running. The next step is to run a function that loads the images and changes them in the GTK window, but I am having trouble getting this to work. Here is my code to setup the window:

```
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "Image Player");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
```

This will run in it's own thread. Now, I want to run this block of code to change and display the image, which is working for a single image when I run them together in one function, but I'd like to simply call a function called changeImage() which reassigns the *image* variable through the updated pixbuf and automatically updates it in the window.

```
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((guchar*)buf_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,
        FALSE, 8, width, height, stride_rgb*3, NULL, NULL);
image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
```

How would I achieve this in GTK? I have just started learning how to use this tool last week, I believe I'm supposed to create an event using g_signal_connect, but I'm not sure how to tie it to a function call like changeImage() where I can simply update the image or call the function and the image in the display window will change.

EDIT: Test script included below:

````
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

FILE *x1, *y_1, *z1;
FILE *x2, *y2, *z2;

// image needs to be converted from greyscale to RGB
// using this structure works with GTK
typedef struct{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
}rgb;

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *image;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *hbox;

// Function to display image 8-bits
// This is the function I was using to display 1 image per window
void displayImage8_RGB(uint8_t *x, uint8_t *y, uint8_t *z, const int width, const int height){
    size_t size = width * height;
    size_t stride_16 = width;
    size_t stride_rgb = width;


    rgb *buf_rgb = (rgb*)malloc(stride_rgb*height*sizeof(rgb));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < height; j++){
            //printf("%d\t%d\n", x, y);
            float y_ = x[stride_16*j+i];
            float cb = y[stride_16*j+i];
            float cr = z[stride_16*j+i];
            cr = cr - 128;
            cb = cb - 128;
            y_ = (y_ * 219) + 16;
            cb = (cb * 244) + 128;
            cr = (cr * 224) + 128;
            
            uint16_t r_ = (y_ + 1.402 * cr) / 255;
            uint16_t g_ = (y_ - 0.344136*cb - 0.714136*cr) / 255;
            uint16_t b_ = (y_ + 1.772*cb) / 255;

            if (r_ > 255){
                r_ = (uint8_t) 0;
            }
            if (g_ > 255){
                g_ = (uint8_t) 0; 
            }
            if (b_ > 255){
                b_ = (uint8_t) 0;
            }

            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].r = r_;
            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].g = g_;
            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].b = b_;
            //printf("x: %d\ty: %d\tz: %d\nr: %d\tg: %d\tb: %d\n", x_c, y_c, z_c, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].r, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].g, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].b);
        }
    }

    GtkWidget* image;

    gtk_init (NULL, NULL);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((guchar*)buf_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,
        FALSE, 8, width, height, stride_rgb*3, NULL, NULL);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Image Viewer");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

    

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();


    free(buf_rgb);
    return;
}

void changeImage(uint8_t *x, uint8_t *y, uint8_t *z, const int width, const int height){
    printf("displaying image\n");
    size_t size = width * height;
    size_t stride_16 = width;
    size_t stride_rgb = width;

    rgb *buf_rgb = (rgb*)malloc(stride_rgb*height*sizeof(rgb));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < height; j++){
            //printf("%d\t%d\n", x, y);
            float y_ = x[stride_16*j+i];
            float cb = y[stride_16*j+i];
            float cr = z[stride_16*j+i];
            cr = cr - 128;
            cb = cb - 128;
            y_ = (y_ * 219) + 16;
            cb = (cb * 244) + 128;
            cr = (cr * 224) + 128;
            
            uint16_t r_ = (y_ + 1.402 * cr) / 255;
            uint16_t g_ = (y_ - 0.344136*cb - 0.714136*cr) / 255;
            uint16_t b_ = (y_ + 1.772*cb) / 255;

            if (r_ > 255){
                r_ = (uint8_t) 0;
            }
            if (g_ > 255){
                g_ = (uint8_t) 0; 
            }
            if (b_ > 255){
                b_ = (uint8_t) 0;
            }

            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].r = r_;
            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].g = g_;
            buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].b = b_;
            //printf("x: %d\ty: %d\tz: %d\nr: %d\tg: %d\tb: %d\n", x_c, y_c, z_c, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].r, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].g, buf_rgb[stride_rgb*j+i].b);
        }
    }

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((guchar*)buf_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,
        FALSE, 8, width, height, stride_rgb*3, NULL, NULL);


    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image), pixbuf);

    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

    //gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    free(buf_rgb);
    return;
}

void* setupWindow(){
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "Image Player");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    
    rgb *buf_rgb = (rgb*)malloc(1998*1080*sizeof(rgb));

    memset(buf_rgb, 255, (1998*1080*3));

    GdkPixbuf *s_pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)buf_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,
    FALSE, 8, 1998, 1080, 1998*3, NULL, NULL);

    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(s_pixbuf);


    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // for demo, pass files in this order:
    // idwt_bin0_test1.raw idwt_bin1_test1.raw idwt_bin2_test1.raw idwt_bin0_test2.raw idwt_bin1_test2.raw idwt_bin2_test2.raw

    // files passed to function are 3 components (.raw) for 2 uncompressed images

    pthread_t win, changer;

    x1 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin0_test1.raw", "rb");
    y_1 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin1_test1.raw", "rb");
    z1 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin2_test1.raw", "rb");

    x2 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin0_test2.raw", "rb");
    y2 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin1_test2.raw", "rb");
    z2 = fopen("mtest/idwt_bin2_test2.raw", "rb");
    // test1 1998x1080
    // busy4k 4096x2160
    const int w = 1998, h = 1080;
    int size = w * h; // multiply by 2 for 16-bit

    uint8_t *xbuf1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);
    uint8_t *ybuf1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);
    uint8_t *zbuf1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);

    uint8_t *xbuf2 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);
    uint8_t *ybuf2 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);
    uint8_t *zbuf2 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*size);

    // comp0 comp2 comp1

    fread(xbuf1, 1, size, x1);
    fread(ybuf1, 1, size, y_1);
    fread(zbuf1, 1, size, z1);

    fread(xbuf2, 1, size, x2);
    fread(ybuf2, 1, size, y2);
    fread(zbuf2, 1, size, z2);


    // thread to setup main gtk window
    pthread_create(&win, NULL, setupWindow, NULL);

    changeImage(xbuf1, ybuf1, zbuf1, w, h); // change to image 1
    sleep(3); // gtk's timer could be used instead
    changeImage(xbuf2, ybuf2, zbuf2, w, h); // change to image 2
    sleep(3);

    fclose(x1);
    fclose(x2);
    fclose(y_1);
    fclose(y2);
    fclose(z1);
    fclose(z2);
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Any call to `gtk*` function should be done in the GTK main thread. When/how do you want to trigger the function exchanging the image? What do you have in which thread? Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what you have so far and what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have included the demo here https://github.com/mrizko-imbed/gtk-display-image-demo. I did not include the image decoder, but the decompressed files are there to be passed as arguments to the program. I planned on creating a separate thread for the gtk_main() and running changeImage() in a main thread. I hope this is acceptable or an MCVE.

Comment: The link shows a 404 message... And the code should be included into the question directly, anyway.

Comment: Right, still new to this. Code is included in the question. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: In `ChangeImage` you add `image` to the window but did not create `image` at all. The function `displayImage8_RGB` would create `image` but is not called. That step is missing. Also as I already mentioned, you must call gtk functions from gtk main thread. You don't do that. You can use some timer functions to trigger exchanging images in main thread.

Comment: Once you have created the image, try `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` to update the content with the new pixbuf. Don't add a new image but reuse the old one.

Comment: Hi, would you mind taking another look? I have just updated the demo script. In my setupWindow() function, I initialize a blank pixbuf to fill the window so it can be set at the right size. Then I run changeImage() the first time, and the GTK_IS_IMAGE assertion fails for the first gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf. However, after the sleep() following the first changeImage(), the second image is displayed with no issue.

Comment: Maybe the first 2 times were not sufficient... You must call your gtk* calls from the gtk main thread. You call it from within `main` but created another thread for gtk. That second thread must do it. You do not sync any threads. When I run your snippet, I get to `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` before `gtk_main` was even reached. You could also terminate main with your second thread pending. Don't do that.

Comment: Any update here? Did you fix your threads usage?

Comment: I am using openCV instead for now, although I may return to gtk if I need to. Thanks for your help. The multithread GTK was working in my test file, but not in the decoder so I switched.